# DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter 'userId'

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have an webapp, that uses jQuery, Ajax and bootstrap in it. When I call deleteRow(userId) or add() function I get a warning:

**DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Requested unknown parameter 'userId' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4**

My jsp code for table is below:

```
<table class="table table-striped display" id="datatable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                            <jsp:useBean id="user" scope="page" type="model.User"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>${user.userId}</td>
                            <td>${product.name}</td>
                            <td>${product.address}</td>
                            <td><img src="${product.imageUrl}"></td>
                            <td><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                            <td><a onclick="deleteRow(${user.userId})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
```

My js scripts:

```
var ajaxUrl = "ajax/users/";
function updateTable() {
    $.get(ajaxUrl, updateTableByData);
}
$(function () {
    datatableApi = $("#datatable").DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "info": true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "userId"
            },
            {
                "data": "name"
            },
            {
                "data": "address"
            },
            {
                "data": "imageUrl",
                "orderable": false
            },
            {
                "defaultContent": "Edit",
                "orderable": false
            },
            {
                "defaultContent": "Delete",
                "orderable": false
            }
        ],
        "order": []

    });
    makeEditable();
});

function deleteRow(productId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl + productId,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
            updateTable();
            successNoty("Deleted");
        }
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("ajax/users")
public class AjaxUserController
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable("userId") int userId)
    {
        service.delete(userId);
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<User> getAll()
    {
       return service.getAll();
    }
}
```

What's the problem? I've tried a lot, but nothing seems to solve this warning.

Comment: it is saying that the property userId does not exist in the column data coming back from your ajax request.  Use the developer tools(F12) in the browser to see the ajax request for the table and the result coming back.  You should see that the property is missing.  Either fix the response to include it or fix the reference in the DataTable setup

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, in response section nothing, except "index".(I know there's supposed to be JSON). So, the problem in json, but when I call getAll() method in ajax controller it works so well. What's the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you are not actually using JSON to build this table.  It is being built from the HTML that you are constructing.  The [data property](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) on the column is for use with a JSON result and should be omitted when building from HTML.  Please give this a try

```
datatableApi = $("#datatable").DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "info": true,
    "columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        {
            "orderable": false
        },
        {
            "defaultContent": "Edit",
            "orderable": false
        },
        {
            "defaultContent": "Delete",
            "orderable": false
        }
    ],
    "order": []

});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. But the problem was that I have extended the controller from the another controller, which has the same getAll() method, but doesn't produce any JSON. Because of that the controller has tried to invoke parent's getAll() method. Very silly mistake, which has costed me 2 days